# Not enough space for Windows 7 System Backup

Tags: backup, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

My primary hard disk only has 617GB used. It is a 1.21TB hard drive.

I am backing up to a newly formatted 931GB drive.

I'm only doing System Backup and not any separate files.

Why is Windows 7 backup saying that I don't have enough space?

Comment: Windows backup is not very intelligent sometimes (most times), I recommend using Easeus Todo backup free edition...http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm